# How do I get Gatling reports to show URLs instead of request_0 etc?

Tags: scala, gatling

I'm new to Gatling, apologies if this is a complete noob question.

The "Details" tab of my Gatling report looks like this:

[image: Gatling report]

The left-hand menu contains all the requests that were made. My problem is that, in all but a few rare cases, they're just labelled "request_x" instead of the URL or filename. So where there is a bottleneck I can't tell what page or resource was causing it.

I found that if I manually edit the .scala file before running the scan, I can change each one by hand, e.g. if I change...

```
    .exec(http("request_0")
        .get(uri01)
        .headers(headers_0)
        .resources(http("request_1")
        .get(uri02)
        .headers(headers_1)))
```

...to..

```
    .exec(http(uri01)
        .get(uri01)
        .headers(headers_0)
        .resources(http(uri02)
        .get(uri02)
        .headers(headers_1)))
```

...it seems to have the desired effect. But I don't want to have to change hundreds of these by hand every time I have a new test to run.

Surely there's a better way?

FWIW I'm generating this scala file using Gatling's "recorder" with an HAR file exported from Chrome, as opposed to running the recorder as a proxy. But I have tried the proxy option and got the same end result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Gatling version 3.9.2 or later, you should have this option in the recorder:
[Use HTTP method and URI as request postfix?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9VRA.png). And if you check it the request names should look like that:

```
request_1:GET_https://www.google.com/complete/search?client=firefox&q=google
```